# How to apply an algorithm to reduce the number of numeric labels displayed in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, expression

I have a point feature class of some thousands of points that actually represent the vertices of an area in a map (in the first place I had a polygon feature which I converted to a point feature class).
I want to display in the map all the points, but to put labels only to some of them according to an algorithm I would like to apply to the "object id" integer attribute.

Eg: Put labels only for even numbers (2,4,6 etc) or for a certain step (eg. 5,10,15 etc).

Is this possible in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Use the label class to write an expression that uses the modulo function `%`.  The modulo function returns the remainder of division.  If you use `[OBJECTID]%2` all the even OBJECTIDs will return 0.  Here I am displaying postal codes for every even objectid record.

[image]

You can easily reduce the labels if the density is too big for you map.  Here you would only label every 5th record.

```
    def FindLabel ([OBJECTID], [ZIPCODE]):
        if int([OBJECTID])% 5 == 0:
            return [ZIPCODE]
```